# Add label to AnyGantt

Tags: label, anychart

Any way to show label on AnyGantt Resource Gantt for each task?
I need to show the label for each task. not the tooltip when mouse is ontop of it.

I found there are labels for project Gantt, when I copy the code to resource Gantt, it seems not work. Any one can help?

```
    // set base labels settings
    timeLine.baseLabels()
            .format('{%Name}')
            .fontColor(palette.itemAt(0))
            .position('left-center')
            .anchor('right-center')
            .offsetX(5);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dxnL72am/
This is a sample copied from anychart, and add above code.

Answer (score 0):

To show labels in timeLine of GanttResource you should use next code:

```
chart.getTimeline().baseLabels(true);
var labels = chart.getTimeline().labels();
labels.format('{%Name}')   
    .fontColor("red")
    .position('left-center')
    .anchor('right-center')
    .offsetX(5);
```

The full source code of [a jsFiddle example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/p3gj2spc/)

Comment: I have added custom label in periods, can I show this custom label? I tried, it doesn't work. but it can show start as label.     https://jsfiddle.net/p3gj2spc/2/

Comment: To show custom labels from period's data it's better to use formatting function. I modified your example with custom labels, now it works. You may check it here - https://jsfiddle.net/p3gj2spc/6/

Comment: Also I may suggest you even better solution, please check this example - https://jsfiddle.net/xdn4e9b2/2/

Comment: That's Great, Thanks!

Comment: Anyway to show progress bar, such as the progressValue showed on project chart. I would like to show it on resource chart?

Comment: Unfortunately it goes beyond the functionality of ganttResource. Showing progress is one of main ideas of ganttProject. That's the basic difference between these two types of Gantt Charts.